# How to add multiple filter using GAPandas4 for Google Analytics Data API

Tags: python, google-analytics-api

I've been working in this project to extract data from GA4 with GAPandas4 but I need to add one extra filter, have tried some options but didn't work it out.

Have someone did it previously? How can I add one more filter to filter `sessionCampaignName` together with `itemBrand`?

I'm quite a beginner so any constructive feedback is great!

```
request = gp.RunReportRequest(
    property=f"properties/{property_id}",
    dimensions=[
        gp.Dimension(name="itemBrand"),
        gp.Dimension(name="sessionCampaignName")
    ],
    metrics=[
        gp.Metric(name="itemRevenue"),
        gp.Metric(name="itemsPurchased")
    ],
 date_ranges=[gp.DateRange(start_date="2023-10-01", end_date="2023-10-15")],
    dimension_filter=gp.FilterExpression(
        filter=gp.Filter(
            field_name="itemBrand",
            string_filter=gp.Filter.StringFilter(value="Name of Brand"),
            )
        )
)
df = gp.query(service_account, request)
df.head()
```

Here's what I tried but the outcome was:

> *one AttributeError: type object 'FilterExpression' has no attribute 'Operator'one AttributeError: type object 'FilterExpression' has no attribute 'Operator'*

```
dimension_filter = gp.FilterExpression(
    filter=gp.Filter(
        field_name="itemBrand",
        string_filter=gp.Filter.StringFilter(value="Brand1"),
    ),
    operator=gp.FilterExpression.Operator.AND,
    child=gp.Filter(
        field_name="sessionCampaignName",
        string_filter=gp.Filter.StringFilter(value="Campaign1"),
    )
)

request = gp.RunReportRequest(
    property=f"properties/{property_id}",
    dimensions=[
        gp.Dimension(name="itemBrand"),
        gp.Dimension(name="sessionCampaignName")
    ],
    metrics=[
        gp.Metric(name="itemRevenue"),
        gp.Metric(name="itemsPurchased")
    ],
    date_ranges=[gp.DateRange(start_date="2023-10-01", end_date="2023-10-15")],
    dimension_filter=dimension_filter
)
df = gp.query(service_account, request)
df.head()
```